# Add Effect to Highlighted Area Using jQuery Map Highlight Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, dictionary

I have an interactive venn diagram using the jQuery Map Highlight Plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/keith/REyPv/2/

I'd like to make the initial highlighted item pulse or glow, because users have commented that they didn't know the diagram was interactive. I've tried adding fade or animate in jQuery but couldn't get it to work. And I think I'd only want the first highlighted item to glow, and not the others once the user starts interacting with it.

Also I'm not sure if I'm highlighting the initial item correctly because I'm repeating code below it, so if there are any suggestions on doing that better I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have always ended up having to hack the plugin for any specific needs.

This takes time so I would just blink the wrapper div instead ...

**EDIT:**

Had a second look at your code and the pulsating effect could be made without
hacking the plugin by just triggering mouseover and mouseout.

http://jsfiddle.net/REyPv/3/

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by blink the wrapper div? Do you mean add an effect to the diagram's container to draw attention to it? I'd really like to add an effect to the diagram itself.

Comment: Yes sorry, add effect to the container is what I meant. Unless you are willing to spend the time hacking the plugin.

Comment: You can even loop through each area and pulsate it once without too much modification.